# How to access the runtime value of a LaunchConfiguration instance within custom launch code (injected via an OpaqueFunction) in ROS2?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add some *dynamic behavior* into my python launch file(s) that depends on the *runtime* value of a/few LaunchConfiguration object(s).

For example, I have a `yaml_file_path` argument:

```
def generate_launch_description():
   yaml_file_path = LaunchConfiguration('yaml_file_path')
   yaml_file_path_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('yaml_file_path')
   ...
```

The yaml file contains a list of entities that I need to generate IncludeLaunchDescription instances for, which will be returned by my `generate_launch_description()` api. For example:

```
#
# Only required for launch processing. These are not node params.
#
module_a:
   prefix: <some folder path>
   ...
module_b:
   prefix: <some other folder path>
   ...
```

I understand I need to define and return an `OpaqueFunction` within my generate_launch_description() method, as below:

```
def generate_launch_description():
   yaml_file_path = LaunchConfiguration('yaml_file_path')
   yaml_file_path_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument('yaml_file_path')

   ...
   variable_includer = OpaqueFunction(generate_variable_include_list, ...<???>...)     # <<<<<<< ??? <<<<<<<<

   return [
       yaml_file_path_arg,
       variable_includer,
   ]
```

The `generate_variable_include_list()` method injected above generates a `module_includes` containing the IncludeLaunchDescription instances for each item in yaml file:

```
def generate_variable_include_list(context: LaunchContext, yaml_file_path: str) -> List[LaunchDescriptionEntity]:
   settings: Dict[str, Any] = parse_yaml_file_to_dict(yaml_file_path)

   module_includes: List[IncludeLaunchDescription] = []
   for (key,value) in settings.items():
      module_includes.append(
         IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
               PathJoinSubstitution([settings[key]['prefix'], "module.launch.py"])
            ),
            launch_arguments=[...]
         )
      )
      module_includes.append(
         LogInfo(msg=(["\tIncluding file: ", PathJoinSubstitution([settings[key]['prefix'], "module.launch.py"])]))
      )
   return module_includes
```

... but, I can't seem to find documentation about the following:

- how to accept the `yaml_file_path` into this `generate_variable_include_list()` function above? (Specifically shown with the `<???>` comment).
  I mean, what type is the argument supposed to be? That is, should I be passing in the LaunchConfiguration object as-is, i.e, `yaml_file_path`, or some post-processed version of it?
- how to use that `yaml_file_path` value in that function?
  That is, since it is an asyncio future, how do I access the resolved (runtime) outcome of that LaunchConfiguration instance within my `generate_variable_include_list()` method? Should I invoke the `perform()` API on the object, or would that cause redundant evaluation of the associated future? Is there any cache that I can lookup instead, at runtime, for the resolved value of this entity?
- And, in a general sense, what if the entity in question was *any* `LaunchDescriptionEntity` object, not just a LaunchConfiguration, and I wanted to obtain its resolved/future value in my OpaqueFunction above?

Some sample code, wherever applicable, would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397123/how-to-access-the-runtime-value-of-a-launchconfiguration-instance-within-custom-launch-code-(injected-via-an-opaquefunction)-in-ros2?/) by [alikureishy](https://answers.ros.org/users/54063/alikureishy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2022-03-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using `OpaqueFunction` you can define the `LaunchConfiguration` variable inside it and use its `.perform(context)` method. You can check it out how I did it [here](https://github.com/Serafadam/interbotix_ros_manipulators/blob/xsarm_control_galactic/interbotix_ros_xsarms/interbotix_xsarm_control/launch/xsarm_control.launch.py#L31)
So, in short

```
def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):
    some_var = LaunchConfiguration('some_variable')
    some_var_runtime_value = some_var.perform(context)
```

I hope this helps

---

**UPDATE** by @130s: Because relying on the content in the external link is fragile as it may become unavailable at anytime, I copy-pasted the essense below.

```
def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):

    robot_model = LaunchConfiguration("robot_model")
    :

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "robot_model",
                default_value=TextSubstitution(text=""),
                description=(
                    "model type of the Interbotix Arm such as 'wx200' or 'rx150'"
                ),
            ),
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
        :

            OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup),
        ]
    )
```

---

Originally posted by [Serafadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/52568/serafadam/) with karma: 170 on 2022-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alikureishy](https://answers.ros.org/users/54063/alikureishy/) on 2022-03-10**:
Thanks @serafadam. The example link you included above takes me to duckduckgo.com. Perhaps you meant to include a github link instead?

**Comment by [Serafadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/52568/serafadam/) on 2022-03-11**:
Ah, sorry, it's fixed now

**Comment by [alikureishy](https://answers.ros.org/users/54063/alikureishy/) on 2022-03-12**:
Thanks @serafadam! The example link is very helpful.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-12**:
+1. I've edited your answer to include the entire info that's needed to make it more self-contained answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered recently that the context object also has a `context.launch_configurations` attribute that is a dict of the names and values of the declared `LaunchConfiguration` variables.

See here

https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/blob/rolling/launch/arg_examples.launch.py#L24

```
for argname, argval in context.launch_configurations.items():
    arg_message = f"'{argname}' has a value of {argval}"
    info_log_items.append(launch.actions.LogInfo(msg=arg_message))
```

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1